# Find matching substrings in an array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a substring that I want to find within an array. How do I print all the matching substrings?

My code is like this:

```
@ar = <DATA>;
@skm = grep{m/SLP/g} @ar;
print "@skm\n";
__DATA__
VEFGSLPPKKKLVESLPMMK
```

I expected output is

```
SLP
SLP
```

In the scalar i can do it by using the `$&`, but I am confused about how to do it in an array. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

`grep` only checks if element from list matched. You might want to use `map` to actually transform list element to what you need, in this case using regex to capture and return transformed list for each element from `@ar` array,

```
my @skm = map {m/(SLP)/g} @ar;
```

Comment: Thank you @mpapec. Special variable are not in array? Like `$&`

Comment: @Hussain no, grep only returns list element if condition evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @Hussain, `grep` has nothing to do with regex matches (e.g. `my @bad = grep { $_ > $max } @nums;`), so `$&` has nothing to do with `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` operator simply returns the subset of the input list where the expression in the first parameter evaluates to a *true* value.

Since your `@ar` array has only a single element, and because that element contains `SLP`, your call of `grep` returns it to you.

It sounds like what you need is `map`, which returns the *result* of the expression in the first parameter when executes in list context. The expression `/SLP/g` returns all occurrences of `SLP` in a string, so

```
map /SLP/g, <DATA>
```

will return a list of all occurrences on `SLP` in any line in the `DATA` file handle.

It is a little more complex if you want all *possibly overlapping* occurrences of a string, but it can be written using a more elaborate Perl regex. This program prints all *overlapping* occurrences of `XXX` from within `XXXXXX`. There are four instances because the pattern can be found starting at the first, second, third, and fourth characters of the target string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

say for map /(?=(XXX))/g, <DATA>

__DATA__
XXXXXX
```

**output**

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
XXX
```